# No me actualiza el campo tipo DateTime con la hora correcta, la deja en "ceros"

Tags: mysql, date

La siguiente consulta me funciona casi perfectamente en mi base de datos MYSQL de no ser porque al momento de ejecutarla usando php el campo 'fechaDePago' en la parte de la hora me la deja en ceros, es decir la fecha me la deja con el valor 2020-03-11 00:00:00 en lugar de 2020-03-11 12:11:11 y la verdad no sé cual es el error, el campo 'fechaDePago' es de tipo DATETIME, agradecería alguna orientación.

> update movimientos 
>                                       set 
>                                       referencia='REFERENCIA',
>                                       formaDePago='Transferencia Bancaria',
>                                       fechaDePago='2020-03-2 12:11:11',
>                                       imagen='fotosMovimientos/28840873549.png'
>                                       where movimientos.id=22

El código php que uso para la consulta es el siguiente:

> ```
>               $sqlInsertar="update movimientos 
>                                 set 
>                                 referencia='".$_POST['referenciaDePagoDeMovimiento']."',
>                                 formaDePago='".$_POST['formaDePagoDeMovimiento']."',
>                                 fechaDePago='".$_POST['fechaDePagoDeMovimiento']." ".$_POST['horaDePagoDeMovimiento']."',
>                                 imagen='".$rutaCompletaDeLaImagenASubir."'
>                                 where movimientos.id=".$_POST['idmovimiento']." 
>                             ";
>                 echo $sqlInsertar; 
>                 mysql_query($sqlInsertar) or die('error al actualizar el movimiento'.mysql_error());
> ```

Comment: Exactamente que valores tienen las variables `$_POST['fechaDePagoDeMovimiento']` y `$_POST['horaDePagoDeMovimiento']`. No sería mejor dejar que MySQL haga el trabajo de poner la fecha usando la función `NOW()`?

Comment: Hola, Gracias por contestar, la hora tiene que ser capturada por el usuario ya que  es una fecha de cuando sucedió tal evento y no es la del momento. La primera variable contiene un valor como "2020-03-2" y la segunda un valor como "12:11:11"

Comment: Ya vi lo que tiene tus variables, ojo que dice `2020-03-2 12:11:11`, es decir el día tiene un sólo dígito, quizás ahí esté el problema

Comment: ya le intente con los días completos y deja igual la hora en ceros

Comment: cómo está configurado el control DateTime? qué parámetros estableces? es posible que no recoja la hora

Comment: Si recoge la hora ya que el query se arma correctamente. El problema es que al ejecutarlo deja la hora en ceros

Comment: Si ejecutas el update directamente en MySQL también sucede lo mismo?

Comment: Si lo ejecuto directamente si lo hace bien :O

Comment: Esto te puede servir: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: No pues arme la parte de la fecha aparte, y ya jaló, la verdad no cual fué la diferencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues lo resolví así:

> ```
>               $fecha=$_POST['fechaDePagoDeMovimiento'];
>                 $hora=$_POST['horaDePagoDeMovimiento'];
>                 $fechaCompleta=$fecha.' '.$hora;
> ```

```
                $sqlInsertar="update movimientos 
                                set 
                                referencia='".$_POST['referenciaDePagoDeMovimiento']."',
                                formaDePago='".$_POST['formaDePagoDeMovimiento']."',
                                fechaDePago='".$fechaCompleta."',
                                imagen='".$rutaCompletaDeLaImagenASubir."'
                                where movimientos.id=".$_POST['idmovimiento']." 
                            "; 
                //echo $sqlInsertar; 
                mysql_query($sqlInsertar) or die('error al actualizar el movimiento'.mysql_error());
                echo "movimiento pagado y referenciado";
```

Comment: No veo diferencia con lo que tenías pero bueno, si te funciona así todo bien :)